Magento 2 : Provide Name Attribute in Customizable Option of Product
I am implementing a functionality where each product have different input field in frontend  where user can input value as per their requirement. It has multi step form in frontend, second step have radio button selection and then add to cart.
Problem: I created custom option for each product but it doesn't have name attribute. name is needed as second option option loaded on the bases of first step input fields.
I am stuck here.
Please help on this.
Thanks in advance

Do you mean you wan to set label before options?

No @DhirenVasoya i want name dom element in input field


Why you want to give name to that one?

Hi @DhirenVasoya on the basis of name i need some customisation on product detail thats why
